# Is it possible to ignore `assert`ions in doxygen generated reference graphs?

Tags: c, doxygen

In my code there are some `assert` calls to ensure that my functions are working properly, and to do some invariant-tests for datastructures.

Sometimes I use functions in the argument of `assert` and this functions then are in Doxygens callgraph of that function. For some bigger invarianttests this really polutes the graph…

How can I avoid that `list_isSorted` in the following snippet occurs in the callgraph?

```
int list_isElem (List l, Element e) {
  assert(list_isSorted(l));
  {
    if (list_isEmpty(l)) { return 0; }
    switch (compare(e, list_getValue(l))) {
    case -1: return 0;
    case  0: return 1;
    case  1: return list_isElem (list_getTail(l), e);
    default: exit(ERR_UNKNOWN);
    }
  }
}
```

I already tried to set `PREDEFINED = NDEBUG` in Doxyfile, but that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just skip the assert?

see hhttp://www.doxygen.nl/manual/faq.html

"The new and easiest way is to add one comment block with a \cond command at the start and one comment block with a \endcond"

automate it with a macro:

```
#define DAssert(x) /** \cond */ assert(x) /** \endcond */
```

Comment: I'd prefer if this work without that much of manual work. I hoped that Doxygen can handle this someway automatically or at least someone can point me to a already existing filter.

Comment: Define a macro that wraps the `assert()` call with the `\cond` and `\endcond` commands.

Comment: I have added another option, that is a bit longer, but doesn't need you to change existing asserts, but only the way you include `assert.h`.

Comment: in the prefix header #define assert DAssert ;) -- I just don't like overriding system commands --also I don't see any answer ;)